# How to use git branch with Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, git-branch

I am new to git. I have a very simple scenario for using git. I had my first release written with Android Studio. Now I want to work with some new features. What I did so far:

1. enabled the VCS in my Android Studio
2. created a local repository for my project from Android Studio
3. pushed my local repository to my Bitbucket remote repository (`$git push -u origin master`)

Now I am confused for the next step: create a feature branch. Should I create a branch in the local repository:

```
$ git branch --track feature1 origin/master
```

or should I create a new branch from the Bitbucket web portal, and clone the new branch?

I also want to know how I can switch branches with Android Studio? For example, switch from feature branch to master branch to work on some hotfix. Do I need to use the Bitbucket plugin to checkout the project very time from the remote repository every time I switch branches or I can hot switch it inside Android Studio?

Thanks!

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You should be able to do this directly from Android studio.

The easiest way is going to the **bottom right corner** of the Android Studio window where you should see the text "Git: branch name", in your case it should say "Git: master". Click on it and it will show a small menu consisting of the different branches available both locally and remotely, also there should be an option "+ New Branch" which will create a new branch for you and switch you to it.

You should then be able to change some code, commit it and push it to remote. Merging and checking out branches can also be done from that same menu. The same thing can also be done from the menubar option "VCS"

Comment: thanks. That looks like what i want to do. I have one more question, I created a branch from command line $git branch --track feature1 origin/master in my local repo, and checkout to that branch. My Android Studio did show i am on the Git:feature1 branch. Then I add a new file in my source folder, the file turns to blue, i think that means a new file added, and not commit yet. Then I switch to the master branch. The file turns to green. What does this mean? I thought if switch to the master branch, i shouldn't see the new added file? Is it?

Comment: here are all the status colors describe http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/checking-git-project-status.html

Comment: thanks for link. But why the master branch shows the file i added to the feature1 branch? if that is the right behaviour, when i compile the master branch, all the changes and files i made in the feature1 branch will also get compiled? i am confused now.

Comment: that I don't know maybe its a bug in android studio.

Comment: i found out why. I need to commit and push the changes when i am on the feature1 branch. Once i did that, everything works fine.

Comment: Ah then you can also stash the changes see http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing all the options and how stashing works

Comment: If you added new branch and can't see it on AS as explained above, update the Project and check again

Comment: don't see the text "Git: branch name" in the bottle right, but the branches are viewable in the VCS->Git->Branches menu option (studio version 1.5.1)

Answer (score 20):

Here's the best way I know to update the remote branches in Android Studio 1.5

1) Go to VCS > Git > Pull (make sure you've pulled your latest changes from master first)

2) Click the blue refresh button on this screen
[image]

3) notice all your new branches show up, click on the checkbox of the one you want to switch to and click "Pull" button

4) go back to the "Git:master" menu in the bottom right of Android Studio, and you'll notice your new branch showed up in the remote section

5) click on the branch you want to checkout and select "Check out as new local branch"

Comment: Good, there is no clear option to update branch list, i tried a lot and after find out you comment, Thanks @whyoz

Comment: @PankajAndroid This also worked for me, after creating a remote branch in bitbucket.  This could definitely be a second option for the answer (until AS has a built-in remote update).

Answer (score 5):

you  can do it easily by the shell (**Git Bash** is recommended) and trying the following for the first time:

```
 git pull [remote] [branch]
```

for example:

```
git pull origin master
```

after this, you can always do the matter without any trouble like that.