# git in Android studio is different from TortoiseGit

Tags: android, git, tortoisegit

I have use the git in android studio and find it is very useful; i use the TortoiseGit, however, i found git in the android studio and TortoiseGit (by right click) the file, are different, I mean the log are different, I try to google it, but found nothing, can I make both to be the same?

Comment: What do you mean by "_different_"?

Comment: the log are different, which means if i submit inside android studio, the submit history won't appear in the tortoise git log

Comment: It is still unclear. Do you mean (A) the actual git commit history (same as doing `git log`) is different? Or (B) just the list of previous commit messages that the app saves is different? Because (A) is impossible, unless your AS and Tortoise are pointing to different repositories. If it's B (which I think it is), then NO, there's no way to sync them because those are 2 separate apps. The commit message history saved by each app is different from the actual git history, so there's no real need to sync them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways:

1. Right click in the git root folder of your project, then TortoiseGit -> Show log. TortoiseGit will show you the whole log, instead of the log only for that file.
2. Or click "Show Whole Project" checkbox in TortoiseGit Log Message dialog (bottom right corner). See the following figure.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Check that your TortoiseGit:

- reference the right local repo (as your Android Studio)
- visualize the same branch (as the one you are working with in Android Studio: see "[How to use git branch with Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35948118/6309)")